# Django database objects not displaying

Tags: python, django, database, shell, object

I keep getting `<QuerySet [<Member:  - >]>` whenever I try to display all objects within a model class through `Member.objects.all()` in the shell.

This is my code, note that the Book class is displaying them correctly when I call all objects, but the Member class does not:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    Titel = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ISBN13 = models.CharField(max_length=13)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Author + ' - ' + self.Titel

class Member(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Surname = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Mailadres = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Birth = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    Leerlingnummer = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name + ' - ' + self.Surname
```

As requested the way I add members:

```
from dashboard.models import Member
a = Member()
Name = 'xxx'
Surname = 'xxx'
Mailadres = 'xxxxxxx'
Birth = 'xx-xx-xxxx'
Leerlingnummer = 'xxxxxxxxx'
a.save()
```

Comment: `self.Name` and `self.Surname` are empty strings for that member

Comment: Are you using python 2.7 or 3+ ?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.2 @SebastianBurzyński

Comment: Most likely self.Name and self.Surname are empty strings, just update your object, and everything should be allright

Comment: I only added 1 member by myself, and I didn't leave those ones empty.. @MosesKoledoye

Comment: Updated multiple times actually, but it just won't work lmao. @SebastianBurzyński

Comment: Can you post the code you use to add the object?

Comment: Have you cranked up the Django Admin and inspected your objects that way? I'd also recommend always including the class and id of an object in the `__str__` result (e.g. `member id=123: the other stuff`)

Comment: BTW, the common convention is to use lowercase names for attributes.

Comment: Updated the post @DanielHepper

Answer (score 0):

You are just creating some variables. You have to assign to the attributes of the object you created and actually save it.

```
from dashboard.models import Member
a = Member()
a.Name = 'xxx'
a.Surname = 'xxx'
a.Mailadres = 'xxxxxxx'
a.Birth = 'xx-xx-xxxx'
a.Leerlingnummer = 'xxxxxxxxx'
a.save()
```

Alternatively, you can use `Member.objects.create`:

```
from dashboard.models import Member
a = Member.objects.create(
        Name='xxx',
        Surname='xxx',
        Mailadres='xxxxxxx',
        Birth='xx-xx-xxxx',
        Leerlingnummer='xxxxxxxxx')
```

Comment: Yes I do, just forgot to put it in the post.